# Remove header for a section Android Amazing Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

In my `ListView` (using library Android Amazing Listview), I have 2 sections and I want to hide the header of 1st section. I tried with

```
view.findViewById(R.id.header).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

in the `bindSectionHeader()` but it doesn't hide the header, instead it would just make it move over my row.

So, is there way to hide the section header for the 1st section? All I need is to show the header of section 2 (to make it visible at all times). Any help is greatly appreciated.

The `ListView` item XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/product_section_header"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/screen11_low_opacity"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/stub" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The header XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/screen11_flag" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: con you provide some sample xml layout?

Comment: yes you should share your code..... and you can make a try with setting height of header to zero...

Comment: XMLs added. @Pankaj Kumar, I don't think it will help because `View.GONE` does that as well. I will still give it a go. Maybe it helps.

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar I tried. I can now say that there are 2 types of headers. One which stays on the list item and the second one which will stay on the top when the section is still visible (but the list item's header has gone up).

Comment: I was able to hide the second type of header but it would come back upon scrolling up.

Comment: Would like the loser (down voter) to come up and state why the down vote. I hope I wasn't getting close to their points score, as that seems the only reason I'd get -1 on this question. :P

Comment: I am facing kind of similar issue don't know how to solve. Need your help in it. I want header with 2 label in one section and in other section with 3 label. I have kept condition, and I am Hiding 3rd label in 1st section and showing in 2nd section. But it is not working. As the `configurePinnedHeader()` will be configured from first visible item in the list i.e. `getFirstVisiblePosition()` of the list. So the pinned header is not showing the 3rd label in other section,as it was hidden in the first section. I don't know how to solve this. Any hint or guidance would be appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: @Dory create a new question with relevant code and post a link here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the  `Android Amazing Listview`, I was able to mould it to satisfy my requirements. So here is what I did...

In `configurePinnedHeader()`, hide the overlay header:

```
if(getSectionForPosition(position)==0){    //hide header
    lSectionHeader.setText("");
    lSectionHeader.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
//in else block, you have to set the background (when you are setting the text)
```

In `bindSectionHeader()`, hide the header which we added in the cell:

```
if(getSectionForPosition(position)==0){
    TextView lSectionTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.header);
    lSectionTitle.findViewById(R.id.header).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```